# How is module/component execution order determined?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

New to React/Gatsby.

As per the docs, in code below, GraphQL results are injected as {data} into IndexPage and it has to wait for GraphQL Query to complete. But how/where is this order defined?

```
const IndexPage = ({ data }) => (
  <Layout>
    //HTML
  </Layout>
);

export default IndexPage;

export const allPostsQuery = graphql`
  query {
    some_name {
      allPosts: postsConnection(orderBy: dateAndTime_DESC) {
        edges {
          node {
            //Query...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution order determined by Gatsby which wraps your React application:

You should refer to [Gatsby Lifecycle APIs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-lifecycle-apis/) for the full information.

[image]

In your case, the execution of the query will come before the rendering of `IndexPage`.